# performance of merged cells in HandsonTable

Tags: handsontable

Using handsontable pro angular, i observe very slow performance when merging cells.  I'm trying to merge A1&A2, B1&B2, ... A3&A4, B3&B4 ... etc, using this approach:

```
...
for (var myCol = 0; myCol < 10; myCol++) {
   mc = { row : myOddRow , col : myCol, rowspan : 2, colspan : 1};
   myMergeCells.push(mc);
}
...
hot.updateSettings({mergeCells: myMergeCells});
```

With a 400 row worksheet (thus myMergeCells has about 2000 elements), the grid appears to be merged quickly... but HOT buffers any user input for another ~30 seconds.

We used similar code in an older angularJS app... and performance was fine.  Any suggestions would be much appreciated!